# Como traer data de REST API para insertar en ORACLE DB

Tags: oracle, rest, postman

Estoy buscando una manera de poder obtener/leer data de un servicio REST para insertarlo en una tabla de ORACLE DB.

He estado buscando pero solo he encontrado el caso contrario.

Estoy utilizando PL/SQL Developer y Postman, necesito otro software?

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

No conozco pl/sql developer. Puedes integrar eso y postman?
Postman solo te permite realizar peticiones a webservices si el webservice es de tipo GET y devuelve información, solo conseguirás obtener ese resultado en el postman.

Si puedes modificar tu la api, podrías crear un webservice tipo POST que primero obtiene datos necesarios y luego los escribe en bbdd.